# Find $x$ to solve the list of congruences: $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3, x \equiv 2 \pmod 5, x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Referring [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479238/find-a-solution-x-of-the-system-of-four-congruences-list-below), I understand how to solve the list of congruences.

However, I was presented this particular example in a book and have one minor question.

It goes:
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies x = 1 + 3k_1, k_1\in\mathbb Z.$$
Then plug into second we get,
$$ 1 + 3k_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies k_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5.$$
Here is where I don't understand. I do not understand how they go from left to right side of arrow. Here is my way:
$$
\begin{align}
1 + 3k_1 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 &\implies 5\mid (1 +3k_1 - 2) \\
&\implies 5 \mid (3k_1 - 1) \\
&\implies 3k_1 \equiv 1\pmod 5.
\end{align}
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $1+3k_1\equiv 2\pmod{5}$, subtract $1$ from each side to get $3k_1\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and then multiply by $3^{-1}$ on each side to get $k_1\equiv 3^{-1}\pmod{5}$.  Now... what is $3^{-1}$ in this context?  It is not the fraction $\frac{1}{3}$ that you'd be used to in the field of rational numbers or real numbers... it is the number who when multiplied by $3$ results in $1$ in the context of this modular arithmetic ring.  Here... $3\times 2 = 6$ which is $1$ more than $5$ so $k_1\equiv 3^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod{5}$

Comment: @JMoravitz, Thanks, that makes sense. I understand $3^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of 3 to get the unity element in this particular ring. Thanks again.

Comment: As an aside, it was quick to spot that $3^{-1}$ was equivalent to $2$ here by inspection, however for larger examples it may not be reasonable to expect to spot what the inverse is equal to at a glance.  In such scenarios the extended euclidean division algorithm and bezout's identity will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multiply by 2 in both sides you'll get $2+6k_1 \equiv 4 \mod 5 \implies 2 + k_1 \equiv 4 \mod 5 \implies k_1 \equiv 2 \mod 5$

Comment: 2 is the inverse of 3 modulo 5

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the end of your answer:
$$3k_1 \equiv 1\mod{5}$$
we can multiply both sides by 2 to get:

$$6k_1 \equiv 2\mod{5}$$
Since,$$ 5k_1 + k_1 \equiv  k_1\mod{5}$$

We know that
$$\Rightarrow k_1 \equiv 2\mod{5}$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).